# migrate Access database to Sharepoint and preserve ID column

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, pnp-powershell, updatelistitems

I would like to migrate access databases to SharePoint Online, and sometimes the built-in migration wizard fails. I can create the missing tables and relink them with a macro, but I have trouble uploading the data. In order not to keep data correct, I need to keep the values in the ID column the same as in the database.

```
Add-PnPListItem -List "Test" -Values @{"ID"=11;"TestColumn"="TestString"}
```

Returns an error saying that the ID field is not updatable. Is there any way to override this ID field temporarily? I am thinking on a workaround to do it reversed, create an empty item first in the list and then look back in the database for the matching record, but I'd like to avoid this, if tere's any other option.

Answer (score 0):

What you would have to do is populate the ID to the value right before the first value in your Access table, e.g. if your Access row starts at ID 10, you'd create items 1 - 9 in SharePoint, then import your data.

Note that Access Services is being deprecated.

Comment: That would only work if the id's were continous. But this is a live database, records were deleted, old id's not reused.

Comment: IDs are continuous in Lists.

Comment: Only during creation. If you have items with ID 1,2 and 3, and delete item with ID 2, the original 3rd item will still have ID 3.

Comment: The SharePoint List Item ID will be 4 in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old question, but what I have found to work is exporting the table to Excel, generating a new table with continuous IDs (and empty "padding" records) using the VLOOKUP function, importing that new table into the Sharepoint list, and then deleting the padding records using an Access query (or you could just leave them if they don't bother you)